# What are some great prerequisite books before tackling IMO level books

Tags: soft-question

I need a book list to establish my foundations in the following topics:
1. Algebra (inequalities,  functional eq. and etc.) 
2. Geometry
3. Combinatorics and Probability
4. Trigonometry
5. Proof writing
6. Problem-solving 
7. Number Theory